# reset or disable/enable curent used TabIndex -runtime- to start with 1 again

Tags: c#, wpf, tabindex, tabstop

I have a TextBox (firstItem) and a Button (anotherItem) on my WpfWindow, indexed with e.g. 1 and 23 (for the sake of simplicity).

So when I click the Button (that has TabIndex="23"), I want, that it resets the curent TabIndex so that the TextBox is Focused. Is that even possible?

I tried:

- to disable and anable TabStop of Button (in ClickEvent) but no result.

could it help, if I use a function that is executed after the ClickEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- Focus the TextBox in CS file (non-MVVM way):

XAML file:

`<TextBox Name="TextBoxFirst"></TextBox> 
<Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>`

CS file:

`private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   TextBoxFirst.Focus();
}`

- Focus the TextBox in XAML (MVVM way):

XAML file:

`<TextBox Name="TextBoxFirst" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="{Binding FocusOnFirstTextBox}"></TextBox>`

CS file:

`FocusOnFirstTextBox = true;`

- Bonus:

You can access the TextBox without knowing it's name.

    `Visual visual=YourGridName;
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        Visual childVisual = (Visual) VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);
        if (childVisual is TextBox)
        {
              TextBox tempTextBox = childVisual as TextBox;
              if(tempTextBox.IsVisible)
              {
              tempTextBox.Focus();
              }
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot (: First option I knew already.. but the problem is: I don't know the name of the `TextBox` AND if I would know: There are several `TextBox`'es on the screen (`Visible` and `Collapsed`). So I don't know which is the first `TextBox` to set your second option to the first `TextBox`

Comment: now I search the `TextBox` relativly and set it via `Focus()`.

Comment: Thanks for your 'Bonus Code'. I changed it a bit to do the work, and it did it (: